# Can't find Oracle.DataAccess.dll

Tags: .net, oracle, odp

My project is using .net framework 4.7 and 8:Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.2.0

As far as I understand Oracle.DataAccess.dll comes with Oracle Data Provider for .NET 4.

Is it right that I need 12.2.0.2 version on odac?
I can't find it, there is only (12.2.0.1.0) on oralce website